# Exception: TypeError: graphqlAzureFunctions is not a function when using Apollo for Azure Functions

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, apollo, apollo-server

My package.json:

```
{
    "name": "azurejs",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "apollo-server-azure-functions": "^2.2.6",
        "graphql": "^14.0.2",
        "graphql-tools": "^4.0.3"
    },
    "scripts": {},
    "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Using code directly ripped out of the apollo example:

```
const { graphqlAzureFunctions } = require('apollo-server-azure-functions');
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools');

const typeDefs = `
  type Random {
    id: Int!
    rand: String
  }

  type Query {
    rands: [Random]
    rand(id: Int!): Random
  }
`;

const rands = [{ id: 1, rand: 'random' }, { id: 2, rand: 'modnar' }];

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    rands: () => rands,
    rand: (_, { id }) => rands.find(rand => rand.id === id),
  },
};

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

module.exports = function run(context, request) {
  graphqlAzureFunctions({ schema })(context, request);
};
```

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v1/servers/azure-functions.html

If I navigate to the endpoint I get the error 'graphqlAzureFunctions is not a function', I did a search of that and indeed I can't find the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed v2 apollo-server packages while used code from v1 tutorial.

Follow [v2 tutorial](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/servers/azure-functions.html), install `apollo-server-azure-functions@alpha`, `graphql` and we may move on with v2 code.

```
const { gql, ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server-azure-functions");

// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`;

// A map of functions which return data for the schema.
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => "world"
  }
};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

module.exports = server.createHandler();
```

Note that in `function.json`, we need `"name": "$return"` while the template uses `"name": "res"` by default.

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: ah drat, can't believe how much time I spent trying to figure this out, going through version histories on git and everything haha